# How to texture Opengl glut objects (C++)

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, glut

I have already tried and succeeded loading a texture from a bmp file, and drawing quads and triangles with texture. However i need to apply the loaded texture to an object drawn with glutSolidDodecahedron and glutSolidSphere. How can i do this? Please include some code if possible

Note: I HAVE to use those functions, I'm not allowed to draw them from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Neither `glutSolidDodecahedron` nor `glutSolidSphere` specifies texture coordinates, at least not according to any documentation that a quick web search turns up. I had a quick look at the FreeGLUT implementations and those do indeed not specify texture coordinates.

If you can use shaders, you can derive the 2D texture coordinates from the 3D location of the vertices. Spheres and dodecahedrons are pretty regular shapes, so you can simply do a spherical projection (convert the vertex position to spherical coordinates and drop the radius component).

Comment: Fixed function OpenGL does supply position dependent texture coordinate generation as well. See glTexGen